# SQL Azure 0.0.0.0 firewall rule

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is setting firewall rule for SQL Azure server on specific IP address (or range) is favored on setting the 0.0.0.0 firewall “Allow Microsoft Services access to this server” rule in term of security ?
As far as I know 0.0.0.0 allow all access from Azure local IPs (but of course to actually connect to the database the specific server name and login username/password will need to be offered).
Using 0.0.0.0 makes the configuration more easy since there is no need to track the role instances IPs in order to enable SQL Azure server connections but it does open some risks.

I would like to hear you opinion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The 0.0.0.0 setting is used internally by Microsoft to allow their services to connect to your SQL instance. Of course, in theory your SQL database is open to any Windows Azure machine out there but it's not like the potential connection surface is the entire world.

Comment: Thanks!
The database connection is accessible by every services even cloud services developed by clients.
I know that it is limited to data centers network only the question is it more preferred the fuss of specific IP rule or going with 0.0.0.0 rule

Comment: That will depend on your personal preferences. It's probably more secure to limit the firewall rules to only your instances, on the other hand you'll be doing more maintenance on the firewall if your VIP changes over time.

Comment: Totally agree I wonder if there are any official security recommendation by Microsoft about the "Allow Microsoft Services access to this server" rule.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,

Allowed Windows Azure Services - Will allow only azure services to access the database.

Secondly,

To be able to access the database server from any other endpoint, you need to add firewall rules to allow those specific IP ranges. If you want to connect from a machine with ip, 132.99.xx.xx you need to add a rule with start IP and end IP as 132.99.xx.xx

It is always a good practice to add the ranges which are necessary, to avoid any chances of attack

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is this answer not upvoted or commented on?